# Leaflet Omnivore - KML fill and stroke colors are always the default blue

Tags: leaflet, kml, mapbox

I'm trying to import kml file and style them.

In my KML, we have different styles for example

```
<Style id="YellowPolyStyle">
        <LabelStyle>
            <color>00000000</color>
            <scale>0</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff6e6e6e</color>
            <width>0.4</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ff00d9ff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="GreenPolyStyle">
        <LabelStyle>
            <color>00000000</color>
            <scale>0</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff6e6e6e</color>
            <width>0.4</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ff009961</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
```

And I calling those style for filling my KML layer. Here is my sample

```
<Placemark id="ID_00000">
  <name>Grid ID: 14</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
  <description></description>
  <styleUrl>#GreenPolyStyle</styleUrl>
  .......
</Placemark>
```

But it is not working. It is filling default Blue colour in the KML layer.

So how can I fix this issue. I am using **Leaflet Omnivore** library for loading the KML.

I manually tried to attach style using **setStyle** function but it is also not working. Here is my sample code

```
var runLayer = omnivore.kml(kml)
  .on('ready', function() {
      runLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      if(layer.feature.properties.styleUrl == "#YellowPolyStyle") {
              layer.setStyle(
                  { 
                    "LabelStyle": {
                      "color": "00000000",
                      "scale": "0"
                    },
                    "BalloonStyle": "",
                    "LineStyle": {
                      "color": "ff6e6e6e",
                      "width": "0.4"
                    },
                    "PolyStyle": { "color": "ff00d9ff" }
                  }
              );
        }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

Unfortunately, Leaflet does not handle complex style sets as in KML format. It looks like in KML, you can specify a family of styles for label, line string, balloon / marker, etc.

Whereas in Leaflet, each feature is styled with an individual spec. Therefore the object that you pass to `setStyle` is not understood by Leaflet. You have to determine first the geometry type (i.e. marker, line string, etc.) and give the corresponding style directly:

```js
runLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (layer.feature.properties.styleUrl === '#PolyStyleOGreen') {
    if (layer.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
      // See Leaflet path layers options
      // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#path
      layer.setStyle({
        color: '#ff6e6e6e', // More red than green and blue => redish color
        weight: 4 
      });
    } else {
      console.log('unknown geometry type');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('unknown styleUrl');
  }
});
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/nJMXrUYp5tzmHuVZn2lm?p=preview

See the [path options](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#path) for available style options in Leaflet.

BTW, you could slightly simplify your code by directly passing a [custom GeoJSON layer group](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers) as 3rd argument of `omnivore.kml`, and specifying its [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-style) option, so that the layers that are built directly get the appropriate style, instead of having to loop through them afterwards to re-style them.

For example:

```js
var myCustomGroup = L.geoJSON(null, {
    style: getStyle
});

function getStyle(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.styleUrl === '#PolyStyleOGreen') {
        if (feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
            return {
                color: '#ff6e6e6e',
                weight: 4
            }
        }
    }
}

omnivore.kml('test.kml', null, myCustomGroup).addTo(map);
```

Updated demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/dJKqyCZn7jOXM9zJfY9u?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I tried your provided answer. But it is not working. It didn't fill any color on the map.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if you do not provide the new code that you have tested and that you say does not work, it is impossible to help you any further.

Comment: This worked great, thanks